# ZIP file not being created, but no error gets triggered

Tags: php, file, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm using ZipArchive:

```
function zip_dir($source, $target){

    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($target, \ZipArchive::CREATE) !== true)
      exit('cannot create zip');

    foreach($iterator as $file){
      $zip->addFile($file);
      print $file . '<br>';
    }


    $zip->close();
    return $target;
}


zip_dir(__DIR__ . '/test/', __DIR__ . '/testarchive.zip');
```

I can see the list of files, but in the end I cannot find the zip file that's supposed to be created. And I get no errors / exceptions from ZipArchive...

edit:

I've added `print $zip->getStatusString();` after `$zip->close();`

and it prints :Can't open file: Permission denied".
What does that mean? I know for sure every directory is writable, bc I can create new files with PHP inside them...

edit 2:

```
if(is_writable(dirname($target)))
  print 'target dir is writable...';
```

it prints that, so the dir is writable. Feels like I'm in the twilight zone...

Comment: Does the user PHP is running under have permission to create files in the directory in question?

Comment: is test directory is writable

Comment: yes, I'm running "wamp" on localhost. it has permission to do anything..

Comment: use try catch and see if code is throwing any exception

Comment: Is addFile returning true or false?

Comment: that one returns false.. but what should I do so it returns true?

Comment: Check phpinfo to see if zip is enabled.

Comment: if you mean the  "zip" extension, yes its active

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two Comments From php.net

If you're adding multiple files to a zip and your `$zip->close()` call is returning FALSE, ensure that all the files you added actually exist. Apparently `$zip->addFile()` returns TRUE even if the file doesn't actually exist. It's a good idea to check each file with `file_exists()` or `is_readable()` before calling `$zip->addFile()` on it.

and

Don't forget to check the zip isn't empty, folks - otherwise the zip won't be created at all, and the server will issue no warning!

Comment: how to check if zip file is empty?

Comment: the numFiles property of $zip is 9. I guess that means its not empty

Comment: and "status" is 5, "statusSys" is 2

Comment: Is 9 the same as the number of rows you print?

Comment: yes but I found the error, see my edit. But now I can't figure out why it says there are permission problems because I know PHP has write and read access to that directory...

Comment: I think it may be adding two directories `.` and `..` totally guess.

Comment: ok i did it in the end. it seems that empty directories trigger this error :|

Comment: I had a problem when adding files and deleting them before closing the archive. Lesson learned: don't delete the files you are adding to the archive before calling close() !!!

Comment: Also when iterating folders, make sure to exclude the first two items in every folder (`.` and `..`).

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you have a permission issue, either with writing to the zip file, or reading the files it is zipping.

I would use a combination of `file_exists`, `is_readable`, and `is_writable` to figure out which of these is causing the problem.

```
function zip_dir($source, $target){

    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($target, \ZipArchive::CREATE) !== true)
      exit('cannot create zip');

    foreach($iterator as $file){
      if (!file_exists($file)) { die($file.' does not exist'); }
      if (!is_readable($file)) { die($file.' not readable'); }
      $zip->addFile($file);
      print $file . '<br>';
    }


    $zip->close();
    return $target;
}

if (!is_writable(__DIR__)) { die('directory not writable'); }
zip_dir(__DIR__ . '/test/', __DIR__ . '/testarchive.zip');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

- All files added actually exist (check each file with `file_exists()` and `is_readable()` before calling `$zip->addFile()`).
- When iterating folder, **exclude `.` and `..`**.
- There is at least one file to zip (`$zip['numFiles'] > 0`).
- Calling `$zip->close()` returns `TRUE`.