# ZipArchives stores absolute paths

Tags: php, directory, zip, php-ziparchive

Can I zip files using relative paths?

For example:

`$zip->addFile('c:/wamp/www/foo/file.txt');`

the ZIP should have a directory structure like:

```
foo
 -> file.txt
```

and not:

```
wamp
 -> www
     -> foo
         -> file.txt
```

like it is by default...

ps: my full code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895089/zip-file-not-being-created-but-no-error-gets-triggered/12895332#12895332) (I'm using ZipArchive to compress contents of a directory into a zip file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [`addFile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) function definition, you can override the archive filename:

```
$zip->addFile('/path/to/index.txt', 'newname.txt');
```

Comment: oh tx. How can I do the same with empty directories? It looks like the addEmptyDir function doesn't have that 2nd argument?

Comment: Just pass the new destination name. I.e., if your source is /path/to/empty then just call `$zip->addEmptyDir("empty");`

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to recursively add all subfolders and files of a folder, you can try the code below (I modified [this code/note in the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php#93090)).

```
class Zipper extends ZipArchive {
    public function addDir($path, $parent_dir = '') {
        if($parent_dir != ''){
            $this->addEmptyDir($parent_dir);
            $parent_dir .= '/';
            print '<br>adding dir ' . $parent_dir . '<br>';
        }
        $nodes = glob($path . '/*');
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            if (is_dir($node)) {
                $this->addDir($node, $parent_dir.basename($node));
            }
            else if (is_file($node))  {
                $this->addFile($node, $parent_dir.basename($node));
                print 'adding file '.$parent_dir.basename($node) . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
} // class Zipper
```

So basically what this does is it **does not include** the directories (absolute path) before the actual directory/folder that you want zipped but instead only starts from the actual folder (relative path) you want zipped.

Comment: Thank's this works greatly! Better than any other code snippet I have ever seen to recursively zip current folder using PHP.

Comment: In fact this solution doesn't store dot files (like .htaccess) because GLOB filters them automatically. There's a workaround for GLOB but you can also use scandir() or opendir(), which in fact are faster. I'll post a code below.

Comment: I already posted just below but don't change your answer, it's already perfect and my answer is just a follow-up from yours :)

Comment: Ah right! I didn't notice your post above/below. Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of Paolo's script in order to also include dot files like .htaccess, and it should also be a bit faster since I replaced [glob by opendir as adviced here](http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/putting-glob-to-the-test/).

```
<?php

$password = 'set_a_password'; // password to avoid listing your files to anybody

if (strcmp(md5($_GET['password']), md5($password))) die();

// Make sure the script can handle large folders/files
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

//path to directory to scan
if (!empty($_GET['path'])) {
    $fullpath = realpath($_GET['path']); // append path if set in GET
} else { // else by default, current directory
    $fullpath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)); // current directory where the script resides
}

$directory = basename($fullpath); // parent directry name (not fullpath)
$zipfilepath = $fullpath.'/'.$directory.'_'.date('Y-m-d_His').'.zip';

$zip = new Zipper();

if ($zip->open($zipfilepath, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open/create zip <$zipfilepath>\n");
}

$past = time();

$zip->addDir($fullpath);

$zip->close();

print("<br /><hr />All done! Zipfile saved into ".$zipfilepath);
print('<br />Done in '.(time() - $past).' seconds.');

class Zipper extends ZipArchive { 

    // Thank's to Paolo for this great snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17440780/1121352
    // Modified by LRQ3000
    public function addDir($path, $parent_dir = '') {
        if($parent_dir != '' and $parent_dir != '.' and $parent_dir != './') {
            $this->addEmptyDir($parent_dir);
            $parent_dir .= '/';
            print '<br />--> ' . $parent_dir . '<br />';
        }

        $dir = opendir($path);
        if (empty($dir)) return; // skip if no files in folder
        while(($node = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            if ( $node == '.' or $node == '..' ) continue; // avoid these special directories, but not .htaccess (except with GLOB which anyway do not show dot files)
            $nodepath = $parent_dir.basename($node); // with opendir
            if (is_dir($nodepath)) {
                $this->addDir($nodepath, $parent_dir.basename($node));
            } elseif (is_file($nodepath)) {
                $this->addFile($nodepath, $parent_dir.basename($node));
                print $parent_dir.basename($node).'<br />';
            }
        }
    }
} // class Zipper 

?>
```

This is a standalone script, just copy/paste it into a .php file (eg: zipall.php) and open it in your browser (eg: `zipall.php?password=set_a_password` , if you don't set the correct password, the page will stay blank for security). You must use a FTP account to retrieve the zip file afterwards, this is also a security measure.