# zip a directory non recursive php

Tags: php, zip, non-recursive

I have no idea if this is possible since there is no information available on the internet. I spend two hours searching without any result.

I am trying to zip a directory without knowing the file names that are in the directory. I tried many methods but they include the whole path, I only want the files in the zip.

I have tried the following:

```
$zipFile = "./testZip.zip";
$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zipArchive->open($zipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE))
    die("Failed to create archive\n");

$zipArchive->addGlob("./*.txt");
if (!$zipArchive->status == ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OK)
    echo "Failed to write files to zip\n";

$zipArchive->close();
```

and:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('myzip.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (glob("target_folder/*") as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
    if ($file != 'target_folder/important.txt') unlink($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried (code), and the exact problems you have run into?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ZipArchives stores absolute paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902387/ziparchives-stores-absolute-paths) - ([This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993105/php-creating-zips-without-path-to-files-inside-the-zip) might also be informative.)